How to avoid a forced shutdown on an Android 13 device for vehicles?
I've bought a Chinese device for my car/motorcycle, which runs Android 13. I don't want to root it to keep the warranty valid, but the device is easy enough to customize: for example, I've been able to change the launcher (I'll use none of the pre-defined apps for music and navigation, and I don't have an iPhone, so the non-customizable home screen UI had no use for me).
The device is meant to be "permanently installed" on the vehicle, not to be detachable: it has a power cable coming out from the back that you have to put in the vehicle and connect with screws, but it also has a USB C port.
Here's the problem: it works fine when powered by the USB C port, but during the startup, a pop-up appears telling you that it will shut down in 5 seconds unless you press "Cancel" (but there are no buttons on the device apart one that only switches it off) and then it shuts down, just to boots again, and then repeat this cycle.
I've been somewhat able to "bypass" that popup using a "scientific method" which is by frantically tapping everywhere on the screen until something happens (like an app starts); if it happens, then the pop-up goes and I can keep the device on as long as I want. I've not been able to find any procedure that grants me to get to this point: I just have to try and try until I succeed.
I'd like better to power it using the USB port on my vehicles, so I'd need a way to know what happens at startup in order to know and disable the app (if any) that opens the pop-up; or maybe I could launch at startup some process (but very quickly) that makes it happy.
I've tried the UAC program, and there's just a handful of proprietary apps in the phone (other than the launcher): they're not even hidden so I can launch them from the apps tray but they are in Chinese and apparently, they do some RAM test or ... nothing visible.

Is there a way to show on screen the processes that are running, so I can see what's alive when it wants to shut down?

Is there a way to add an app that will start at startup before anything else?

Does someone have other ideas about how to detect/block/disable the process that wants to shut down the phone if not powered by the power cable?


This is the package list obtained with ADB:
android
android.auto_generated_rro_product__
android.auto_generated_rro_vendor__
android.ext.services
android.overlay.dynamicNavBar
android.overlay.navbar
com.android.backupconfirm
com.android.bips
com.android.bluetooth
com.android.bluetoothmidiservice
com.android.bookmarkprovider
com.android.calllogbackup
com.android.captiveportallogin
com.android.carrierconfig
com.android.carrierdefaultapp
com.android.certinstaller
com.android.chrome
com.android.companiondevicemanager
com.android.cts.ctsshim
com.android.cts.priv.ctsshim
com.android.dialer
com.android.documentsui
com.android.dreams.basic
com.android.dreams.phototable
com.android.dynsystem
com.android.egg
com.android.emergency
com.android.externalstorage
com.android.gallery3d
com.android.hotspot2
com.android.htmlviewer
com.android.inputdevices
com.android.internal.display.cutout.emulation.corner
com.android.internal.display.cutout.emulation.double
com.android.internal.display.cutout.emulation.tall
com.android.internal.systemui.navbar.gestural
com.android.internal.systemui.navbar.gestural_extra_wide_back
com.android.internal.systemui.navbar.gestural_narrow_back
com.android.internal.systemui.navbar.gestural_wide_back
com.android.internal.systemui.navbar.threebutton
com.android.internal.systemui.navbar.twobutton
com.android.keychain
com.android.localtransport
com.android.location.fused
com.android.managedprovisioning
com.android.mms.service
com.android.modulemetadata
com.android.mtp
com.android.musicfx
com.android.networkstack
com.android.networkstack.permissionconfig
com.android.nfc
com.android.ons
com.android.overlay.wallpaperconfig
com.android.packageinstaller
com.android.pacprocessor
com.android.permissioncontroller
com.android.phone
com.android.printspooler
com.android.providers.blockednumber
com.android.providers.calendar
com.android.providers.contacts
com.android.providers.downloads
com.android.providers.downloads.ui
com.android.providers.media
com.android.providers.partnerbookmarks
com.android.providers.settings
com.android.providers.telephony
com.android.providers.userdictionary
com.android.provision
com.android.proxyhandler
com.android.se
com.android.server.telecom
com.android.settings
com.android.settings.intelligence
com.android.settings.overlay.oversea
com.android.sharedstoragebackup
com.android.shell
com.android.simappdialog
com.android.smspush
com.android.sprd.telephony.server
com.android.statementservice
com.android.stk
com.android.storagemanager
com.android.systemui
com.android.theme.color.black
com.android.theme.color.cinnamon
com.android.theme.color.green
com.android.theme.color.ocean
com.android.theme.color.orchid
com.android.theme.color.purple
com.android.theme.color.space
com.android.theme.font.notoserifsource
com.android.theme.icon.roundedrect
com.android.theme.icon.square
com.android.theme.icon.squircle
com.android.theme.icon.teardrop
com.android.theme.icon_pack.circular.android
com.android.theme.icon_pack.circular.launcher
com.android.theme.icon_pack.circular.settings
com.android.theme.icon_pack.circular.systemui
com.android.theme.icon_pack.circular.themepicker
com.android.theme.icon_pack.filled.android
com.android.theme.icon_pack.filled.launcher
com.android.theme.icon_pack.filled.settings
com.android.theme.icon_pack.filled.systemui
com.android.theme.icon_pack.filled.themepicker
com.android.theme.icon_pack.rounded.android
com.android.theme.icon_pack.rounded.launcher
com.android.theme.icon_pack.rounded.settings
com.android.theme.icon_pack.rounded.systemui
com.android.traceur
com.android.vending
com.android.vpndialogs
com.android.wallpaper
com.android.wallpaper.livepicker
com.android.wallpaperbackup
com.android.wallpapercropper
com.asus.soundrecorder
com.carletter.car
com.chartcross.gpstestplus
com.google.android.apps.maps
com.google.android.apps.restore
com.google.android.configupdater
com.google.android.ext.shared
com.google.android.feedback
com.google.android.gms
com.google.android.gms.location.history
com.google.android.gmsintegration
com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
com.google.android.gsf
com.google.android.inputmethod.latin
com.google.android.onetimeinitializer
com.google.android.overlay.gmsconfig
com.google.android.overlay.gmsgsaconfig
com.google.android.partnersetup
com.google.android.printservice.recommendation
com.google.android.projection.gearhead
com.google.android.syncadapters.calendar
com.google.android.syncadapters.contacts
com.google.android.tts
com.google.android.webview
com.mdc.nasoni
com.microsoft.launcher
com.redstone.ota.ui
com.softwinner.explore
com.sprd.autoslt
com.sprd.cameracalibration
com.sprd.cameraipcontrol
com.sprd.engineermode
com.sprd.logmanager
com.sprd.omacp
com.sprd.powersavemodelauncher
com.sprd.systemupdate
com.sprd.uasetting
com.sprd.validationtools
com.spreadtrum.proxy.nfwlocation
com.spreadtrum.sgps
com.spreadtrum.vce
com.unisoc.aicore.uscaiengine
com.unisoc.launcher.customization
com.unisoc.mssv
com.unisoc.storageclearmanager
com.waze
com.zqc.agingtesttool
com.zqc.audioroute
com.zqc.camera
com.zqc.functioncore
com.zqc.launcher
com.zqc.screensaver
com.zqc.usb.mediaplayer
com.zxbluelet
org.chromium.browser

